# Local folder not writable - installing packages offline in R

Tags: r, offline

I know this is a common topic, but existing answers have not helped me.

I am working on a "secure lab" environment, where I have no access to the Internet, and no Admin rights. There is a local folder I can modify. I have access to a list of R packages (in zip format, and win-binaries), and I need to install them in my local folder.

I first set the working directory (where I have excel files and other stuff I want to use in R):

```
setwd("~/localfolder")
```

Then, I copy the R packages from the admin repository to another local folder, and add this path to the libraries:

```
.libPaths("~/Rpackages")
```

Then, I install one package from the local folder:

```
install.packages("readxl_1.1.0.zip", repos = "NULL", type = "win.binary")
```

But I get an error:

```
 Installing package into `~/Rpackages' (as `lib' is unspecified)
 Warningin install.packages("~/Rpackages/readxl_1.1.0.zip", : 
 `lib = "~/Rpackages/"' is not writable
 Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
 path[1]="\\[network system files folder]\R\win-library\3.3": Access is denied
 In addition: Warning message:
 In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
 path[1]="\\[network system files folder]/R/win-library/3.3": Access is denied
```

This is very weird, because `~/Rpackages/` **is writable**. I just copied the R package there!

So, as you can see, I have set the local path correctly, which is pretty much the common solution to all related problems. I feel the problem is trivial but I just cannot figure it out! Any idea?

Comment: can you share actual permissions on `~/Rpackages` after running `ls -l` on `~/` ?

Comment: @ErikKornet I'm in Windows. It says the local user owns it (i.e. me). Actually, the problem solves when restarting Rgui. The problem is fully reproducible. I just need to run `install.packages` with an error, and then re-run correctly and the problem arises. I had the problem because I tried several previous erroneous commands without restarting R. Sounds like a bug.